# Creating grid in ArcGIS Pro that looks exactly same as Corner Label Grid in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-pro, grids-graticules

When creating a grid in ArcMap I would choose the Label Style Format of Corner label in the Grid Properties dialog box.

I am attempting to create the same grid in ArcGIS Pro, I understand you have to use Tags to alter how the grid looks. But I can not replicate the grid, so if `X is 500000` and `Y is 6265000` ArcMap would display it as Small 5, Large 00 followed by small 000 for the X and the Y coordinate would be displayed as small 62, large 65 followed by small 000.

The tags I have currently used to format the grid in ArcGIS Pro is as follows:

How would I replicate this is in ArcGIS Pro. I have attached two images to try to better explain.

[image: Example of how the grid should look compared to how ArcGIS Pro displays it currently]